# How to show taxonomy terms from wordpress database?

Tags: metabox, taxonomy

I am trying to show all terms associated to "competition" taxonomy as dropdown in my metabox, but it is not showing up.

```
<p>
<label for="match_competition_name"><?php _e( 'Comtetition', 'match_details' ); ?></label>
<select name="match_competition_name" id="match_competition_name">
<?php 
global $wpdb;
$get_comtetition=$wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM 'wp_term_taxonomy' WHERE  'taxonomy' = 'competition' ");
foreach($get_comtetition as $row){
?>
<option <?php echo (match_details_get_meta( 'match_competition_name' ) === $row->post_title ) ? 'selected' : '' ?>><?php echo $row->post_title;?></option>
<?php } ?>
</select>
</p>
```

Comment: I think you meant to show terms of a taxonomy? if so please use: `$terms = get_terms($taxonomy, array('hide_empty' => false));` Where $taxonomy is your custom taxonomy slug. e.g. 'competition'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution One:**

get_terms() - Retrieve the terms in a given taxonomy or list of taxonomies.

You can fully inject any customizations to the query before it is sent, as well as control the output with a filter.

The ‘get_terms’ filter will be called when the cache has the term and will pass the found term along with the array of $taxonomies and array of $args. This filter is also called before the array of terms is passed and will pass the array of terms, along with the $taxonomies and $args.

`get_terms` returns an array of objects. You cannot echo an array, if you do, you will just get Array(). What you can do is `print_r($array)` or `var_dump($array)` to see the data it contains.

```
$taxonomy = 'shirt';
$args=array(
  'hide_empty' => false,
  'orderby' => 'name',
  'order' => 'ASC'
);
$tax_terms = get_terms( $taxonomy, $args );
foreach ( $tax_terms as $tax_term ) {
    echo $tax_term->name;
}
```

**Solution Two:**

You can use the function called `get_taxonomies()` in order to query out the taxonomy that you need.

**Syntax:**

```
 <?php get_taxonomies( $args, $output, $operator ) ?>
```

**Example:**

This example uses the 'object' output to retrieve and display the taxonomy called 'genre':

```
<?php 
$args=array(
  'name' => 'genre'
);
$output = 'objects'; // or names
$taxonomies=get_taxonomies($args,$output); 
if  ($taxonomies) {
  foreach ($taxonomies  as $taxonomy ) {
    echo '<p>' . $taxonomy->name . '</p>';
  }
}  
?>
```